# How to play a sound of paticular frequency and framework not found AudioUnit question

Tags: iphone

How to play a sound of paticular frequency and framework not found AudioUnit question1. I want to play a sound of paticular frequency.
Can anybody tell me which function should I use for this purpose.

2.I can not use the iPhone SDK in AudioUnit Framworks.
Compile time, the following error.

Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0-arch i386-isysroot / Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.2.1.sdk -L/Users/gl/Desktop / BY/Apps/t5/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/gl/Desktop/BY/Apps/t5/build/Debug-iphonesimulator-filelist / Users/gl/Desktop/BY/Apps/t5/build/t5. build/Debug-iphonesimulator/t5.build/Objects-normal/i386/t5.LinkFileList-mmacosx-version-min = 10.5-framework Foundation-framework UIKit-framework CoreGraphics-framework AudioUnit-o / Users / gl / Desktop / BY / Apps/t5/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/t5.app/t5
ld: framework not found AudioUnit
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Please help me.

Comment: Please make two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

use AudioToolBox instead of AudioUnit even i was having same problem. it got solved by using audiotoolbox.
 For playing frequency check this code
"/Developer/Examples/CoreAudio/SimpleSDK/DefaultOutputUnit"
and
http://atastypixel.com/blog/2008/11/04/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

m also doing the same thing. hope so it will help you.

Comment: For me, this didn't work. I also have CoreAudio.framework. As a matter of fact, if I remove any of these frameworks I get many linking errors. But if I have the three of them, I get a single linking error 'Framework not found AudioUnit'. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Anyone understand why this error shows up in the first place?