# iOS - Generate tone at specific frequency and volume

Tags: audiounit, audioqueue, audiosession

I have to make ear testing app like Audiogram. I have to calibrate headphone at specific frequency and volume. I have to generate beep tone at specific frequency and volume and output volume of sound should be same of headphone. Could you please anyone help me?

Comment: A simple search on stackoverflow or google will give you many results. 
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iOS+tone+generator
Setting the volume and and frequency are pretty trivial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play Beep Sound in iphone Related to the Frequency & Decibels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943896/play-beep-sound-in-iphone-related-to-the-frequency-decibels)